# Console Output - Random Number Appearing

Tags: c++, console, iostream

I'm using OpenGL/Glut/GLM to import and render a model to my screen.

When I'm outputting to the console when the model is loaded or a key is pressed, a number follows the output... I've noticed it a few times now...

The format I use is: `std::cout << "\nW key pressed\n" << std::cout;` etc...

I hope this isn't a stupid question, but what is that number? And why is it appearing? Can I stop it?

[image: console]

Comment: Why are you streaming `std::cout` to itself?

Comment: [GLM](https://glm.g-truc.net), [GLM](http://devernay.free.fr/hacks/glm/), or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the address of `std::cout`.  It's showing up being you are inserting `std::cout` into `std::cout`.

Get rid of the `std::cout` at the end of your statement:

```
std::cout << "\nW key pressed\n";
```

Comment: Ah, so simple. I can't believe I haven't noticed this before. Thanks for posting. I'll accept your answer as soon as it lets me.